# How to send an image to a Javascript client using JSON from a Java server

Tags: java, json, google-api, signpost

I am working on Google Contacts API and I received all data and sending as string to JSON (javascript) but when I get an image from contacts I can receive image.  How can I send it to JSON? How can send the image file to a URL? (Can I use signpost?)

```
if (photoLink.getEtag() != null) {
 GDataRequest request = myService.createLinkQueryRequest(photoLink);
 request.execute();                                                                                    
 // No Authentication header information  
 InputStream stream = request.getResponseStream();    
 Image image=  ImageIO.read(stream);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to send the actual image encoded as data using JSON, you can just send an HTML `img` tag with the `src` attribute containing the encoded image data, like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7">
```

Browser Support List (Includes Android Browser & iOS Safari:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Comment: I believe it's the best option.  Here's some more info: http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Data_URIs_and_Inline_Images .  Base-64 ensures more persistent transfers across networks.  If you use JPEG compression, your images will be very small and for that you would use the `image/jpg` MIME type instead of `image/png` above.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a servlet for sending images and just send some url variable in JSON. (like `?pic_id=034enifuwbf0329` .

You *could* use inline image, but that would fail miserably on certain IE versions, while the other solution is browser-agnostic.

Comment: It will be sending to Mobile browser.

Comment: then bandwith is of paramount importance. The base64 encoding of inline image is terribly ineffective, in terms of compact data transfer. Stick with solution #1, have a dedicated servlet for serving images.