# would like my java rest service to return a image ( png ) to be rendered on page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, rest

tried reading on SO - but am not very clear.
have not yet tried any code - so have nothing to show.
My Java REST service returns JSON data with a flag indicating if an image exists with image name.
Now I want to retrieve the image using JQuery.
$1
Should I store the image in database as BLOB and return some kind of byte array ?
$2
in one of the SO posts :
"You should simply use a servlet for sending images and just send some url variable in JSON. (like ?pic_id=034enifuwbf0329 "
from here :[How to send an image to a Javascript client using JSON from a Java server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302863/how-to-send-an-image-to-a-javascript-client-using-json-from-a-java-server)

how is that done  - the option 2 ?

so which option is better ?
any other option that I should use ?
the client is a browser not a mobile

Comment: The format of this question makes it hard to read.

Comment: and I thought I was pretty clear .... :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly:

Storing the image path in the DB rather than a long blob/data url is more much effecient in my opinion. Have a DB column named filepath or something and then when you want to display it you can output

```
<img src="(insert DB response filepath)">
```